# Modify the label of a predefined property Python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm using the location property as shown below but I wonder how I can change the label of it to be "New Location" instead of "Location"?

```
ob = bpy.data.objects['Rock']    
row = layout.row()
row.column().prop(ob, "location")
```

This is what appears:

[image]

Comment: @RayMairlot noted and edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add in the `text` argument when adding the property, e.g.:

```
row.column().prop(ob, "location", text="New Location")
```

This overrides the default label. You can see the additional options for UI properties in the [API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.UILayout.html?#bpy.types.UILayout.prop).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to display only one of the axis instead all the x,y and z?

Comment: Have a look at the `index` property in that api link. If you can't get it working, ask another question.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working. Any advice regarding setting the unit? (my other question).

Comment: what if I wanted to include x and y only not z? As it accepts an int not list

Comment: I suggest asking a new question. I have a solution, but a) These comments are getting away from the original answer and b) I cannot easily answer in a comment.

Comment: Okay, I'll ask another question, I managed to do it by using two props one for x and another for y, not sure if this is your solution?

Comment: Yes that's the solution. No need to ask a question then.